# What is --rm used in docker build for?

Tags: docker

So when I use

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t test_1 .
```

I create an image that can be ran with `docker run`. But what is the point of using `--rm` in `docker build .`? Isn't the image being eliminated?

Comment: The _intermediate_ images get deleted, if the build is successful, not the final one. All the flags are explained on https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: @AymDev uhm I don't think so. I was looking for a why is it usefull answer

Comment: @jonrsharpe but after doing that, using `docker images` does not show up any image, show what is the point?

Comment: @user18088386 it's about intermediate images, the question I flagged yours as a duplicate explains it in its answer, don't just read the title.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on trial for `--rm` in `docker build` is working to automatically delete/destroy the container after process stop. Also can be check with command `docker ps -a`

Comment: Voted down because this is not what the documentation states. The `--rm` option is actually enabled by default and "Removes intermediate containers after a successful build". This is usually desired behavior, but it can be suppressed using `--rm=false`.